# How can I use Java Stream to reduce with this class structure?

Tags: java, java-stream

This is the example of the class I'm working on

```
public class TestReduce
{
    private static Set<Integer> seed = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Accumulator> accumulators = ImmutableList.of(new Accumulator(ImmutableSet.of(5, 6)), new Accumulator(ImmutableSet.of(7, 8)));

        accumulators.stream()
                .forEach(a -> {
                    seed = a.combineResult(seed);
                });

        System.out.println(seed);
    }
}

class Accumulator
{
    public Accumulator(Set<Integer> integers)
    {
        accumulatedNumbers = integers;
    }

    public Set<Integer> combineResult(Set<Integer> numbers) {
        // Do some manipulation for the numbers 
        return (the new numbers);
    }

    private Set<Integer> accumulatedNumbers;
}
```

I would like to reduce all of the `Accumulators` to just a set of numbers but with the initial value. However,  I cannot change the signature of the method `combineResult`. In the example, I did this by just using `forEach` but I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way or java stream way to achieve this? I tried using `reduce` but I couldn't quite get the arguments of the `reduce` right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer for [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61160534/1))

This doesn't seem like a good approach. You're just unioning some sets.

If you can't change the signature of `combineResult`, you can do:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> seed =
    Stream.concat(
        initialSet.stream(),
        accumulators.stream()
            // Essentially just extracting the set from each accumulator.
            // Adding a getter for the set to the Accumulator class would be clearer.
            .map(a -> a.combineResult(Collections.emptySet()))
            .flatMap(Set::stream))
        .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
```

---

For a generalized `combineResult`, you shouldn't use `reduce`, because that operation may be non-associative.

It's easy just to use a plain old loop in that case.

```
Set<Integer> seed = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2);
for (Accumulator a : accumulators) {
  seed = a.combineResult(seed);
}
```

This avoids the principal issue with your current approach, namely non-thread locality of the calculation state (that is, other threads and previous invocations of the loop cannot affect the current invocation).

Comment: Ah sorry I wasn't clear in the question but the operation in the `combineResult` can also be anything else I just use that as an example. I will update the question.